# Multiple mouse but only 1 active until user release control

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any simple script that when i have lets say 3 mouses connected to a single PC but only 1 could active until the current mouse release control?

e.g.
manager: mouse 1
supervisor: mouse 2
staff: mouse 3.

if manager controlling the session, mouse 2 and 3 would be disabled.
vice versa for when mouse 2 controlling the session, mouse 1 and 3 would be disabled.

to release there should be a button for current user to let go of control and other mouse user can go and click the same button to gain control.
there should be only 1 mouse cursor though.

please help, been scratching my head for this.

Comment: This is something operating system drivers manage. There is no way to control it using Javascript.

Comment: 3 people using same computer or you want to collaborated editing https://togetherjs.com/ ?

Comment: 3 people using the same 1 computer only.
we only had 1 PC and vnc/teamviewer or anything needed more than 1 pc wont help due to resource limitation. tq

Comment: that's strange! i think its not possible to manage more than one mouse in a webpage using javascript or anything... browser events and javascript won't be able to distinguish which mouse is moved and its origin ( like supervisor or staff.